# Listbox update global list contents

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, listbox, frame

I'm making a GUI where users import CSV files, and can click on various buttons that carry out functions on these files, e.g. graphing the CSV, viewing a mini table of the CSV, etc. Whenever a file is imported, it gets appended to a global list called `file_list`, and my functions act on the files via this global list.

I have a `Listbox` I am displaying in the mainframe where I want to display a list of files the user has imported. I'm using a for loop to display the name of each file in the `Listbox`, but it just doesn't seem to be working. Any tips on how I could go about displaying these file names? Here's the code I have for the main `Frame` and `Listbox`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import Text, Scrollbar, Toplevel

file_list = []

# i'm just including openfile here, which is essentially an import button. 

def openfile():
    name= askopenfilename()
    # file_list is appended with name everytime openfile is clicked
    rev = (name[::-1])
    i = rev.index('/')
    name = ((rev[:i])[::-1])
    file_list.append(name)
    main_dataview.insert(0, name)
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        data = list(reader(f))
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    # popups a message notifying what was imported
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=" %s was just imported" % (name), font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    center(popup)
    popup.mainloop()

class CODAQ(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "CODAQ")

        # main frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # creates the menubar at the top of the window  
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)

        # import menu for importing csv files, initializes openfile() functions
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Import a CSV File", command = openfile)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Remove", command = remove)
        menubar.add_cascade(label= "File", menu=filemenu)

        # plot menu for creating graphs and figures    
        Plot = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0 )
        Plot.add_command(label="Plot Most Recent CSV", command= popupgraph)
        Plot.add_command(label="Plot an Imported CSV", command = dataselection_graph)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Plot", menu=Plot)

        # viewdata menu for viewing data in a table
        ViewData = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        ViewData.add_command(label="View most recent CSV" , command = viewcsv)
        ViewData.add_command(label="View an Imported CSV",command = dataselection_viewcsv)
        ViewData.add_command(label="View most recent CSV Variables",command = variable_extractor)
        ViewData.add_command(label="View an Imported CSV's Variables", command = variable_extractor_sel)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "View Data", menu = ViewData)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}
        # cycles through screens 
        for F in (WelcomeScreen, MainPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(WelcomeScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    # WelcomeScreen Object
class WelcomeScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Welcome to CODAQ", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Begin by importing your Data", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=0,padx=5)
        label2.pack(pady=15,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter CODAQ",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button.pack()


    # mainpage object
class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="My Data", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row= 0, column = 0, pady = (10,15), padx = (90,0))

        main_dataview = tk.Listbox(self, font=NORM_FONT)
        main_dataview.config(width = 44, borderwidth = 7)

        main_dataview.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan = 2)

        # scroll bar functionality     
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=main_dataview.yview)
        scroll_y.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        # bind txt to scrollbar
        main_dataview.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)


app = CODAQ()
# size of screen 
app.minsize(width=1000, height = 500)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: probably this `for` is executed at start when `file_list` is empty. It is not executed automatically when `file_list` chanages content. You have to update `Listbox` manually when you add new element to `file_list`.

Comment: @furas how would i go about updating it manually? i tried using updateidletask but i'm not sure how it works

Comment: `updateidletask` is for redrawing widgets but you have to use again `main_dataview.insert(0, file)` to add elements to `Listbox` every time user imports new file.

Comment: but `main_dataview` belongs within the `Mainpage` class, and when i add `main_dataview.insert(0,file)` to my import function, it says that `main_dataview` is undefined

Comment: You would show full code to understand problem. Do you add file names to `file_list` **before** you start program or **during** running program ? If **before** then your code should work, if **during** then you have to manually add this name alos to `main_dataview` - but you may have to use `self.main_dataview` and do other this - so it can be more complex and we can't explaint it without full code.

Comment: i'm gonna include more code in the question, one second

Comment: i updated the question. hopefully it makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `self.main_dataview` to have access to `Listbox` from other functions/classes.

I put `openfile()` inside `class CODAQ` to have access to `self.frames` and to `self.frames[Mainpage].main_dataview` - so now I can insert imported files

```
self.frames[MainPage].main_dataview.insert(0, name)
```

---

BTW: `tkinter` should have only one `Tk()` window and one `mainloop()` - so use `Toplevel` to creat popup window and remove second `mainloop()`. Or use existing message windows like

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('!', " %s was just imported" % (name))
```

To get file name without full path you can use

```
name = os.path.basename(name)
```

---

Working code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import Text, Scrollbar, Toplevel
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

import os.path

MEDIUM_FONT = (20, )
LARGE_FONT  = (20, )
NORM_FONT   = (20, )

# i'm just including openfile here, which is essentially an import button.

class CODAQ(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "CODAQ")

        # size of screen
        self.minsize(width=1000, height = 500)

        self.file_list = [] # <--

        # main frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # creates the menubar at the top of the window
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)

        # import menu for importing csv files, initializes openfile() functions
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Import a CSV File", command=self.openfile) # <--
        #filemenu.add_command(label="Remove", command = remove)
        menubar.add_cascade(label= "File", menu=filemenu)

        # plot menu for creating graphs and figures
        Plot = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0 )
        #Plot.add_command(label="Plot Most Recent CSV", command= popupgraph)
        #Plot.add_command(label="Plot an Imported CSV", command = dataselection_graph)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Plot", menu=Plot)

        # viewdata menu for viewing data in a table
        ViewData = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        #ViewData.add_command(label="View most recent CSV" , command = viewcsv)
        #ViewData.add_command(label="View an Imported CSV",command = dataselection_viewcsv)
        #ViewData.add_command(label="View most recent CSV Variables",command = variable_extractor)
        #ViewData.add_command(label="View an Imported CSV's Variables", command = variable_extractor_sel)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "View Data", menu = ViewData)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}
        # cycles through screens
        for F in (WelcomeScreen, MainPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(WelcomeScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


    def openfile(self):
        name = askopenfilename()

        # file_list is appended with name everytime openfile is clicked
        #rev = (name[::-1])
        #i = rev.index('/')
        #name = ((rev[:i])[::-1])

        name = os.path.basename(name) # <---

        self.file_list.append(name)

        self.frames[MainPage].main_dataview.insert(0, name)  # <--

        with open(name, 'r') as f:
            data = list(reader(f))

        showinfo('!', " %s was just imported" % (name))

        #popup = tk.Toplevel() # <--
        #popup.wm_title("!")
        # popups a message notifying what was imported
        #label = ttk.Label(popup, text=" %s was just imported" % (name), font=NORM_FONT)
        #label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        #B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
        #B1.pack()
        #center(popup)

# --- WelcomeScreen Object ---

class WelcomeScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Welcome to CODAQ", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Begin by importing your Data", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=0,padx=5)
        label2.pack(pady=15,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter CODAQ",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button.pack()

# --- mainpage object ---

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="My Data", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row= 0, column = 0, pady = (10,15), padx = (90,0))

        self.main_dataview = tk.Listbox(self, font=NORM_FONT)
        self.main_dataview.config(width = 44, borderwidth = 7)

        self.main_dataview.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan = 2)

        # scroll bar functionality
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.main_dataview.yview)
        scroll_y.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        # bind txt to scrollbar
        self.main_dataview.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

# --- main ---

app = CODAQ()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing because you've left so much out of your question, but here's a runnable example that shows updating the contents of a `tk.Listbox`.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont
    import ttk
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="My Data")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 15), padx=(90, 0))

        main_dataview = tk.Listbox(self)
        main_dataview.config(width=44, borderwidth=7)
        main_dataview.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        for file in file_list:
            main_dataview.insert(tk.END, file)

        # make attributes for other methods to use
        self.main_dataview = main_dataview
        self.next_file_number = len(file_list) + 1

        # scroll bar functionality
        scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=main_dataview.yview)
        scroll_y.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        # bind txt to scrollbar
        main_dataview.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

        # something to create new listbox entries
        add_button = tk.Button(self, text='Add file', command=self.add_file)
        add_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

    def add_file(self):
        """Add a file to the listbox."""
        self.main_dataview.insert(tk.END, 'file_{}'.format(self.next_file_number))
        self.next_file_number += 1

# define global variable
file_list = ['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3']

root = tk.Tk()
mp = MainPage(root, None)
mp.pack()  # MainPage is a widget, needs to have layout manager method called upon it
root.mainloop()
```